# Laravel Redis Session

Tags: laravel, session, redis

In our application, we are using Redis to store the sessions. I have a request that requires running one background job for a user and at the end of the job I need to invalidate all active sessions for the user.

Any ideas on how can I get all sessions for a user from Redis in order to delete them?